# Image cannot be retrieved from the cloudinary server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cloudinary

I m using the `Cloudinary Gem` for the management of images. I'm a new bie to ruby on rails so not being able to find where i am wrong. The uploading of images to the cloudinary server is done but i m not able to retrieve the images from the server. i m putting my views, controller and uploader class over here. Ive installed the carrier wave and also pasted it before the cloudinary gem in the gem file as mentioned.

Controller `console.rb`

```
class ConsoleController < ApplicationController
layout 'console'
def c_view
 @img = Image.new
end
def create
@img = Image.new(params[:img])
  if @img.save
   redirect_to(:action => 'c_view')
  else
   render('c_view')
  end    
 end
end
```

ImageUploader class

```
class ImageUploader < CarrierWave::Uploader::Base
 include Cloudinary::CarrierWave
def store_dir
  "uploads/#{model.class.to_s.underscore}/#{mounted_as}/#{model.id}"
end
version :standard do
  process :eager => true
  process :resize_to_fill => [1200, 800, :north]          
  end

version :thumb do
 eager 
 resize_to_fit(200, 200)
end

def public_id
 return model.photo_file_name
end
end
```

Views

For Uploading

```
<%= form_for :img, :url => {:action => "create"} do |f| %>

<%= f.label :gallery, "Gallery"%>
    <%= f.select :gallery, ["Art", "Bike", "Landscape", "Other", "Portrait"] %> 

    <%= f.label :photo_file_name, "Title" %>
<%= f.text_field :photo_file_name %>

<%= f.label :camera_model, "Camera" %>
<%= f.text_field :camera_model %>

<%= f.label :lens_used, "Lens" %>
<%= f.text_field :lens_used %>

<%= f.label :shutter_speed, "Shutter Speed" %>
<%= f.text_field :shutter_speed %>

<%= f.label :aperture, "Aperture" %>
<%= f.text_field :aperture %>

<%= f.label :iso, "ISO" %>
<%= f.text_field :iso %>

<%= f.label :description, "Description" %>
<%= f.text_area :description, :rows => 2 %>

<%= f.file_field :image %>      

<%= f.submit "Submit", class: "btn btn-success"%>

<% end %>
```

For Displaying

```
<%= image_tag (@img.image_url :thumb, :width => 200, :height => 200) %>
```

Model Image

```
class Image < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user
 attr_accessible :id, :user_id, :name, :camera_model, :lens_used, :shutter_speed,   :aperture, :iso, :gallery, :description, :photo_file_name, :photo_file_size, :photo_updated_at, :image, :image_url 
mount_uploader :image, ImageUploader
end
```

It is not showing any error. The uploading part is working but retrieval of the image is not working.
Please help.

Answer (score 1):

Oh My God...!!!!

I am the dumbest of all.. Sorry guys.. Rofl...!!

i didnt put the show in the controller. So only these line has to be added in the controller and the view are as follows:

In controller

```
@images = Image.all
```

In View

```
<% @images.each do |img| %>
  <%= image_tag(img.image.url (:thumb))
<% end %>
```

Thanks